# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer este arreglo (traido desde una consulta sql) para después guardar la suma total de sus valores?

Tags: php

hace poco que he estado desarrollando con PHP y en mi presente proyecto me encontré con un problema que he buscado solucionar desde hace varios días pero no lo he logrado.

Empiezo explicando lo que busco hacer:
Tengo un dashboard en el que quiero mostrar el total de productos vendidos, para eso mismo he traído tal información desde una base de datos. Esos datos los obtengo mediante un array, que debo recorrer para sumar sus valores, y ese es mi problema, no he logrado recorrerla y sumarlos.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
        $consulta = $conexion->prepare('SELECT botella FROM barezzito WHERE idm = :idm');
        $consulta->execute(array(':idm' => $idMesero));
        $respuestas = $consulta->fetchAll();
        //Aqui obtengo los datos y los guardo en $respuestas
```

Al realizar un print_r() de $respuestas, obtengo la siguiente informacion del arreglo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 3
            [0] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 4
            [0] => 4
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 3
            [0] => 3
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 1
            [0] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 3
            [0] => 3
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [botella] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

Y quiero sumar cada valor de cada botella. Lo he intentado con ciclos *for* y *for each* pero en el primer caso obtengo un error al cargar la pagina y en el segundo me imprime una string 'array' para cada valor del arreglo.
De esta manera lo he intentado con un *ciclo for* sin exito:

```
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare('SELECT botella FROM barezzito WHERE idm = :idm');
        $consulta->execute(array(':idm' => $idMesero));
        $respuestas = $consulta->fetchAll();

        $iBotella = count($respuestas);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $iBotella; $i++) {
            $totalBotella += $respuestas[$i];
        }
```

Espero haberme explicado de la mejor manera, por adelantado muchas gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: puedes hacer un `'SELECT sum(botella) FROM barezzito WHERE idm = :idm'`

Comment: Que tipo de datos en la BBDD es `botella` ?

Comment: @srJJ es de tipo INT (Entero).

Comment: y no te sirve de la forma que menciono Byro ?, es la mas ideal, siendo el caso, nocesitas algo mas ?

Comment: Hola @Bryro, ¡lo he hecho tal como dices y me funcionó!, solo que para mostrar el valor use un 'foreach' apuntando al arreglo en su posición 0, ¿Hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo? Igual muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @srJJ Así es, el comentario de resolvió mi problema, ¿Cómo señalo que ya me ha dado una respuesta?

Comment: La verdad no se, hace rato no navego en el SO, así que no tengo idea, creería que con estos comentarios ya si los ven ta entenderán.

Comment: ya puedes agregar el gancho a la respuesta! no lo hice porque estaba del mobile cuando la vi y es algo tedioso publicar desde el.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

el opcion `sum()` sql suma las columnas de una resultado

```
SELECT sum(botella) FROM barezzito WHERE idm = :idm
```